# How to get a clean BigQuery schema when using a BigTable source?

Tags: google-bigquery, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

BigTable: a simple table with a string key and one column family, `publication_number`, also a string.

This table can be mounted as a dataset in BigQuery by following [Google's instructions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable).

When querying this table I'd expect to see a simple two-column output: `rowkey` and `publication_number`, both `STRING`. Instead I see this:

[image: BigQuery Schema]

BigQuery adds a `.column`, a `.column.name`, `.cell`, `.cell.timestamp`, and finally the value is in `.column.cell.value`.

Is there a way to simplify this to only have:

```
rowkey              STRING
publication_number  STRING
```

And nothing else? I can change both how the table is created and how the export is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to create a logical view over the table that exposes the schema that you want:

```
CREATE VIEW dataset.publication_view AS
SELECT
  rowkey,
  cell.value AS publication_number
FROM dataset.publication_table,
UNNEST(publication_number.column)
```

---

The following does the same as above, but it allows adding additional columns to the view:

```
CREATE VIEW dataset.publication_view AS
SELECT
    rowkey,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT cell.value FROM UNNEST(publication_number.column)), "") AS publication_number
FROM `dataset.publication_table`
```

Comment: Thank you, the view method appears to work well. Hope you don't mind that I edited your answer to add the way we used to create the views. Our method allows adding additional columns to the view in a trivial copy-paste way. The question didn't explicitly ask for that, but our problem needed it :)

Comment: To others coming across this question, you can also use views to reconstruct RECORD types. It gets more complex as you need to use `SELECT AS STRUCT` and join on column qualifiers.

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully that will be useful to other people with a similar question.

Comment: Exactly. I was surprised not not find any instructions on how to do this. Maybe few people are using BigQuery on their BigTables. We find this function extremely handy.